# What's The Best Approach To Make Navigation Sidebar In Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a simple application where i want to have the sidebar navigation fixed and once  i click on when of the buttons of the sidebar the content just change in the center of the borderpane.
you can see the image below :
[image]

And the structure of the simple project:
[image]
And the code for HomeController :

```
package com.example.sidebarnav.Controllers;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HomeController implements Initializable {
    public Button btnStock;
    public BorderPane Bpane;
    public Button btnClients;
    public Text text;
    public String Active="home";

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        // event on click Stock button
        btnStock.setOnAction(event -> {
            Active = "Stock";
            showStock();
        });

        // event on click Clients button
        btnClients.setOnAction(event -> {
            Active = "Clients";

            showClients();
        });

    }

    public  void  showStock(){
        Bpane.setCenter(text);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Fxml/Stock.fxml"));

        try{
            Bpane.setCenter(loader.load());

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public  void  showClients(){
        Bpane.setCenter(text);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Fxml/Clients.fxml"));

        try{
            Bpane.setCenter(loader.load());

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Any Suggestion would be Appreciated.

Comment: I would do it the same way. Easy and readable. You can use different Scenes too, but IMO this makes the code only more unreadable. Domain/Subject complexity is something you can not avoid. Technical complexity you can influence. Plus in the past, I ran into some strange behaviour while changing Scenes while using multiple Scenes in a single Stage.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75514636/2423906) is one idea.  My guess is that `spSubScene.getChildren().add(overviewSubsceneController.getVBoxRoot());` is `Bpane.setCenter(loader.load());` in your case.

Comment: Thank you guys for your instructions , appreciate that

Comment: If you’ve figured out a solution, you can post and accept an Answer to your own Question.

Comment: if someone want's to make an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey guys , as they said in the comments, the best way is to make it simple where you could have a bordpane or any node you want then you could just whenever a user click the button just load the fxml file and Set new View to the center of  the BorderPane.
you can check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75512717/javafx-change-anchorpanes-inside-window-when-button-is-pressed/75514636#75514636)